# How to make input type disabled and button enabled after certain time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a questionarrie form in which after 60 second the radio button would become disabled and next button enabled but I am not getting any idea on how to implement it

```
<form action="">
  <p id="some_div"></p>
  <input type="radio" >
  <input type="radio" >
  <input type="radio" >
  <input type="radio" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

js for the same

```
<script>
  $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
</script>
<script>
  var timeLeft = 60;
  var elem = document.getElementById('some_div');
  var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        doSomething();
    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
        timeLeft--;
    }
  }

  function doSomething() {
    $(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the submit *"Next"* button initially as attribute: `disabled`
- Use a className i.e: `"next"` for your *"Next"* button
- Use a `name` attribute for your radio buttons
- You had an extra *vain* second. You don't need the `else` block inside the `countdown` function:

```js
var timeLeft = 5;
var elem = document.getElementById('some_div');
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
  timeLeft--;
  elem.textContent = `${timeLeft} seconds remaining`;
  if (!timeLeft) {
    doSomething();
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  }
}

function doSomething() {
  $('[name="a"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="a">
  <input type="radio" name="a">
  <input type="radio" name="a">
  <input type="radio" name="a">
  <button class="next" disabled>Next</button>
  <div id="some_div"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: i want to make such that if radio button is selected than button will be enabled before time

Comment: @joshua but that's not stated in your question. Now this comments makes it even more unclear what you're actually after.